# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'RNA'

Tags: python, anaconda

I have installed Anaconda in Ubuntu and then installed the ViennaRNA in anaconda using the following command:

`conda install -c bioconda viennarna`

But when I run the code:

`import RNA`

It shows the following error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'RNA'`

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I used `python3.6 -c import RNA` instead of `python -c import RNA` and it worked.

Comment: Both **should** work if your system PATH is correctly pointing `python` to the proper version. Sounds like you should be using virtualenvs to limit your module scope